# Optimization of cbrt() in C++

Tags: c++, optimization

I am trying to improve the speed of my code, written in C++. Based on profilers, the function `cbrt()/cbrtf32x` is the function I spend the most time in/on (or more specifically):

```
double test_func(const double &test_val){
    double cbrt_test_val = cbrt(test_val);
    return (1 - 1e-10*cbrt_test_val);
}
```

According to data, I spend more then three times the time for `cbrt()/cbrtf32x()` than for the closest cost-expensive function. Thus I was wondering how to improve this function, and how to speed it up? The input values range from `1e18` to `1e30`.

Comment: What is `cbrt()` actually? Also if you have working code to review for improvements, the better site to ask is probably [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: It calculates the cube root of (x). But if that site is better suited for my problem, I will head there.

Comment: You probably need to add more context there (as you are required here also). Without seeing the implementation of `cbrt()` its unlikely anyone could give you advice how to improve it for performance.

Comment: Of course I can create a MWE, but I am not sure how much that will help, especially after it is difficult to reflect how it is embedded in the real code...

Comment: Is your code using the [standard `cbrt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cbrt)?

Comment: Yes, `std::cbrt()`, which then is linked to cbrtf32x, according to the profiler

Comment: How slow is that cubic root? How many times you call it and how long it takes?

Comment: Just as there is a fast inverse square root (in hardware nowadays), there is also a fast inverse cube root (though not in hardware) which you can use if you decide that the extra performance is worth the reduced precision, which we cannot determine without context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little that can be done if you are doing the cubic roots one at a time, and you want the exact result.

As is, I would be surprised if you can improve the cubic root calculation more than 10-20% - if that - while getting the same result numerically. (Note: I got that 10%-20% number out of thin air; it's an opinion, not a scientific number at all.)

If you can batch up the calculations, you might be able to SIMD the operation, or multi-thread them, or if you know more about the distribution of the data (or can find out more,) you might be able to sort them and - I don't know - maybe calculate an incremental cubic root or something.

If you can get away with an approximation, then there are more things that you can do. For example, you are calculating the function `f(x) = 1 - cbrt(x) / 1e10`, which is the same as `1 - cbrt(x / 1e30)` which is a strictly decreasing function that maps the domain [1e18..1e30] to the range [0..0.9999]. With `y = x / 1e30` it becomes `f(y) = 1 - cbrt(y)` and now `y` is in the range [1e-12..1] and it can be pre-calculated and approximated using a look-up table.

Depending on the number of times you need a cubic root, how much accuracy loss you can get away with (which determines the size of the table,) and whether you can sort or bucket your input (to improve the CPU cache utilization for your LUT look-ups) you might get a nice speed boost out of this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here and also interested in gofaster cube roots. My research problem involves solving many cubic equations. I have surveyed the various published algorithms looking for the best one for my application. Curiously there is **enormous** variation in how they benchmark and perform IRL and by compiler!

My benchmarks are in cycles but don't quite reflect real world performance so I'll also include the timing for a testcase as an applied use of it in context. This simple minded code isn't too bad but unprotected against overflows.

```
double qcbrt(double x)
{  // this is current best buy - fast and accurate
  double t, y;
  if (x) y = exp(log(abs(x)) / 3); else return x;
  if (x<0) y = -y;
  t = y*y*y;
  y = y - y * (t - x) / (2 * t + x);  // Halley is good enough wings ~6eps 
  // NB GNU uses y = y * (2 * x + t) / (2 * t + x); which loses precision
  return y;  
}
```

The only way to know for sure is to try each of them in the context where you will use them and pick the fastest. Most of the Unix ones are variants on Kahan's magic constant algorithm but with vastly different speeds on some compilers and differing accuracy.

If I wanted one I thought might be faster than the snippet above I would try the Sun version available here [Sun FreeBSD cbrt by Bruce Evans](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/lib/msun/src/s_cbrt.c)
The other faster **and** more accurate one is in the latest Intel C 2023 system library and uses an FMA trick in Halley's method to get amazing accuracy.

The timings for the various cuberoots that I obtained are as follows:

| Algorithm | cbrt | TestIRL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Intel | 23 | 160 |
| GCC | 175 | 630 |
| MS | 136 | 275 |
| pow 1/3 | 80 | 255 |
| qcbrt | 34 | 240 |
| BSD | 150 | 280 |
| GNU | 145 | 300 |
| Sun | 15 | 217 |

Apart from compilers system cbrt all the rest are compiled MSC 2022 arch AVX2. The last 3 are all variants of Kahan's algorithm and for reasons that escape me completely BSD is faster on GCC clocking in at just 40 cycles! Intel times for each of them are all faster than MS or GCC.

Benchmarks are an artificial test and it doesn't help to obsess on them - what really matters is which one is fast and accurate enough for your problem. Try the Intel 2023 compiler would be my other suggestion.